# 240Vac circuit breaker on 110Vac circuit

Tags: mains, circuit-breaker

I'm wiring up a 110Vac circuit, and for various reasons I'd like to use a [specific breaker](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/weidm%C3%BCller/2822120000/16517898). This breaker is rated for 240Vac circuits. Is it ok to use it for 110Vac circuits? It mentions that the 2 pole version can be used for 120Vac, but is that just related to split-phase stuff?

Comment: Which specific breaker. The data sheet lists several options.

Comment: @Andyaka - This is not important, 1 phase, 2 or 3. They tripping mechanism there is only connected over this plastic connection. In the triple pole version there are three of the 1 pole breaker over the plastic lever connected.

Comment: @MikroPower my question was aimed at the op and not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.
The circuit breaker has only a magnetic and thermic tripping, so it is not depended on which voltage it is running.

The voltage ratings are only for the security distance of the components inside of the breaker.

Comment: Just an addendum -- for switches, and by extension _just the switch part_ of a circuit breaker, you can safely go down in voltage, at least within reason.

Comment: Yes, because the current is doing all the work.